# How to define bash as default Windows Terminal command processor?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

Microsoft has released a preview version of [Windows Terminal at Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701), which allows process commands using [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/getting-started-with-windows-powershell?view=powershell-6), Command Prompt and Bash (using [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)).

Since PowerShell is default processor, everytime the terminal is launched, I need to change it again to Linux Bash.

Is it possible to define the default processor as Linux instead of keep reseting it over and over?

Comment: How do you launch the terminal?

Comment: It is not yet oficially released, so you have to build it on your own [from sources](https://github.com/microsoft/Terminal/) or download preview version from [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701). Generally it should be installed as any other UWP application

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to click 'Settings' menu entry in the drop down menu
[image: Options drop down menu]

Then a settings json file should be opened in your default JSON editor. Please look for 'profiles' section and copy guid for your bash profile.

[image: profiles section]

Then just paste copied guid in 'globals' section's 'defaultProfile' key:

[image: globals section]